# Trying to find some Tags via a collection of where clauses in .NET Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.0

i'm trying to find all the tags which equal a name from a list of words.

for example :-

```
public class Tag
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string UserId { get; set; }
}

// Arrange.
var searchWords = new List<string>(new [] {"c#", ".net", "rails"});
var tags = new Tags
               {
                   new Tag { Name = "c#" },
                   new Tag { Name = "pewpew" },
                   new Tag { Name = "linq" },
                   new Tag { Name = "iis" }
               };

// Act.
// Grab all the tags given the following search words => 'c#' '.net' and 'rails'
// Expected: 1 result.
var results = ???

// Assert.
Assert.NotNull(results);
Assert.Equal(1, results.Count);
Assert.Equal("c#", results.First());
```

I've been trying to use `Any` or `Contains` but my code just doesn't compile.

NOTE: Can be .NET 4.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
var results = tags.Where(t => 
    searchWords.Contains(t.Name, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Also note that since `results` is `IEnumerable<T>` you will need to use the method `results.Count()` instead of the property `results.Count` in your assert.  `Count` is a property defined by the `ICollection` interface.

Comment: Indeed yes, unless you call `.ToList();`.  :)

Comment: Bonus points for making this an invariant string compare :) (ie. don't worry about the case of either strings (in either list).

Comment: Bravo lad! I was worried it would be an answer with `IndexOf` somewhere deep down in the middle of the query. Take my green tick with humble compassion and know that you have made someone, somewhere Down DownUnder ... happy.

Comment: Glad to hear it... uh... mate.